# Bootstrap- 2 stacked divs on small screen. Next to each other, pushed to the left on large screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to Bootstrap and it's been super helpful. But there's one case I can't quite figure out.

I've added a picture of what I need. Desktop view and Mobile view respectively.

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFSi.png)

Here's some code that I tried, but it didn't quite work the way I wanted it to.

```
<div class-"row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
    <img src="./path/to/logo" alt="logo" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
     <p>Company Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated folks!

Comment: There is a typo: `class-"row"` .. other than that the code meets your expectations

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using bootstrap 4 or 5.
What you have to do is simply use 'col-12' along with your col-lg-2 and col-sm-12